# Loop over multiple df and apply factor labels

Tags: r, loops

I have a number of df in r, all with the same column names. I want to reorder the factors. When I do this to just one df, I can do:

```
df$Col1 <- factor(df$Col1, levels = c("One","Two", "Three"))
```

How would I apply this function to all of my dfs? I just want to order them to make it easier in ggplot.

Here is an example with just one df:

```
# Just create some factor data
sex <- factor(c("male", "female", "female", "male"))
# We see the order of factors is female, male
levels(sex)
[1] "female" "male" 

# I want them to be in the opposite order
sex <- factor(sex, levels = c("male", "female"))
# Now they are in the order male, female
levels(sex)
[1] "male"   "female"
```

Comment: can you add a small reproducible example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These `data.frames` should really be in a list if they are so similar, it's much cleaner and more convenient to use R functions.

Here's what you could do:

```
df_list <- lapply(list(df1,...,dfn),function(df){
  df$Col1 <- factor(df$Col1, levels = c("One","Two", "Three"))
  df})
```

You get your list of modified data.frames, that you should really leave there.

BUT then if you REALLY want to put these data.frames in your environment you can do :

```
list2env(df_list,.GlobalEnv)
```

**EDIT:**

Here's how to put all your dfs into a list without enuerating manually, we create the variable names with `paste0` and we get their values with `mget` (which is a vectorized `get`). The following will create a list containing `df1`, `df2` and `df3`:

```
df_list0 <- mget(paste0("df",1:3))
```

Comment: I have a value set as all my df names: `names = "df1" df2"`. Can I use the value `names` in place of `list(df1,...,dfn)`?

Comment: Yes, with `mget` and `paste0` I'll update my answer tomorrow

Comment: But this additional complexity illustrate my main point, work with lists in the first place :). Use answers to this post only if you inheritate this mess from someone else, else fix it upstream.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten about you, I now edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, things will be much easier if you put your data.frames in a list. But if you want to do it the hard way you certainly can:

```
## Make up some example data
df1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("one", "two", "three"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("one", "two", "three"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Get data.frames names. You may need to filter on additional criteria
dfs <- Filter(function(x) is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())

## Iterate over the data.frame names and transform them.
for(df in dfs) {
    assign(df, transform(get(df),
                         Col1 = factor(Col1,
                                      levels = c("one", "two", "three"))))}
```

The `get` function is the active ingredient here. See `?get` for details.